# Create marathi web site in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have understood the concept of globalization and also applied to the demo code  but now i want to create the marathi web site for that how can i get marathi language in the .resx file( which font help to write in to the marathi language) in to the asp.net

Comment: just type in marathi in resource file for a key

Comment: but how can i get these marathi words without any marathi font in asp.net

Comment: find the font file like ttf, woff and use @font-face css and apply

Comment: ok i find the ttf file but where to be install that file to get type word as marathi

Answer (score 0):

use the `@font-face` and keep the `marathi.ttf` inside the folder where you define css file

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MarathiFont';
    src: url('marathi.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('marathi.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
         url('marathi.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
         url('marathi.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
         url('marathi.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
    }

body {
       font-family: 'MarathiFont', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```